# MVC create view dropdownlist language

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I am working on a MVC project where in the create view for a content item I am creating I have a dropdownlist which contains a list of Languages like: us-US, de-DE and nl-NL.

I want to make it so that when I select a language the text in the create view changes to the language you selected.

Is this possible?

Comment: Clarify more so that we can understand your question and help you. Where are you facing problem? In getting dropdownlist for language? or you have that dropdown working but you want to learn translating the page according to language selected in dropdownlist.

Comment: I have a dropdownlist of languages.

Comment: When I select a language I want all the content below to change language to the language you selected in the dropdownlist

Comment: That's possible. Either you can use Google Translate or you can use Resource files if you've limited languages to translate.

Comment: But how am I able to do this?

Comment: [NET-Localization-using-Resource-file](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file). This will help you. If you still don't get idea you can ask.

Comment: [creating-and-using-resources](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-and-using-resources/)